# Colorbox + Flowplayer IE6 Issue

Tags: jquery, css, colorbox, internet-explorer-6

Can anyone tell me why IE6 hates the combination of Colorbox + Flowplayer on the following page: [url removed] (click on the middle teaser labeled "Learn Your Options" to open the video). In all other browsers it's displaying just fine, but IE6 has half of the modal cut off and not aligned center. Any advice would be greatly helpful, thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not just you. IE6 hates everybody.

Comment: Hah, I feel only marginally better now knowing that I haven't been singled out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I did to address this was remove "overflow:hidden;" from the first line of the colorbox.css file. This allowed the whole video to display, though instead of being centered, the left edge of the video ran along the vertical middle of the page.

What I did next was applied a negative left margin equal to half the width of the video using a conditional IE6 comment. This was easy since I was displaying inline content, but your results may vary if you're loading through an iFrame or some other method. You could also choose not to support IE6's nonsense and then you wouldn't even have this problem!